# Regarding equating file attributes in "ls" command

Tags: terminal, osx

I have a folder in which there are thousands of images. Of those thousand images, I want to bring together all those images whose “Last created” and “Last modified” attributes are exactly same.
( In other words, I want to separate all the images I didn’t ever rename for example )

Is there a way to do this from terminal ?

these are the two commands that I want to concatenate
**ls -tU** lists file by creation date. (I'm on a mac)
**ls -lt** lists file by modified date

such that I want to
**"List files whose date created = date modified"**

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `stat` command.  Here is a simple script which prints the filenames, with some allowances for embedded blanks:

```
#!/bin/sh
find $* -exec stat -f '%m %B %N' {} \; | \
awk '$1 == $2 { \
  s=length($1)+length($2)+3;
  $0 = substr($0,s);
  print $0;
}'
```

The `%m` and `%B` are respectively the *modified* and *birth* times (which appear to be what was asked).  The script prints those as decimal numbers, passing to `awk` which then prints only the lines where those numbers are the same.  Because your filenames may have embedded blanks, the rest of the script removes the timestamp values from the input and prints the remainder of the line.

Further reading:

- [How to use the stat command on OS X to display a file or directories creation date / time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826010/how-to-use-the-stat-command-on-os-x-to-display-a-file-or-directories-creation-da)
- [stat/readlink - Display the status of a file](http://ss64.com/osx/stat.html)

Answer (score 0):

I felt bored and I have use for such a script as well so I changed Thomas Dickey's in little ways, not in any drastic way but just e.g. so that you can deal with all sort of file names (even those with newlines) and easily change the separator between the file names (e.g. just set `ORS` to `"\0"` to forward it to `xargs -z …`)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
find "${1-.}" -type f -exec stat --printf '%n\0%Y %W\0' -- {} \; | \
awk 'BEGIN {
  RS  = "\0";
  FS  =  " ";
  ORS = "\n";
} {
  if (NR % 2) {
    f = $0;
  } else if ($1 == $2) {
    print f;
  }
}'
```

Not entirely POSIX because of e.g. `--printf`.

Comment: OSX `find` manual page does not mention `-printf` (my script does work with OSX).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Oh damn, I missed the "osx" tag.

Comment: Also, newlines are [rarely used](http://invisible-island.net/ded/ded.html#features) in filenames, other than as an example on this forum.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I know, I know. Apart from maybe a security aspect POV (for when you are dealing with user-controlled input) there is no good reason for trying to cope with all that craziness concerning all possible file names. I do it mostly out of fun (it's kinda like a puzzle sometimes) but also to train myself for cases where it then really has relevance for security for once.